# Why activities in custom entity disappear when I'm deleting email activity in microsoft crm?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I hope someone can help me.
I've created a custom entity in CRM 2015 and the activity section (note section) is visible.
everything works fine, but then I noticed that in one specific record,
if I delete one email record, then all the other activities disappear. and when I'm creating a new one everything is shown again.
if I change the filter from all to some other value, then I will see records that fit the filter. The issue seems to be only on the "all" filter.
any ideas?
[image]
[image]

Comment: We need more than this to help you. Any screenshots?

Comment: thank you for your comment, I have added a screenshot